# Cannot resize textarea back to original size after using jquery's animate?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Simple problem, but I can't figure out what's up here.

I have a `textarea` that I expand when the user clicks on it. The expanding works a-ok. However, after its been expanded, I can't resize it back to its original size with my mouse, I can only resize it back to the dimensions that it stopped at after the `animate`

**Textarea**

```
<textarea placeholder="Click me!"></textarea>
```

**Code**

```
myTextArea.on('click', function() {
  myTextArea.animate({
    'height': '150px'
  }, 'slow'));
```

[Here's a fiddle showing the problem in action](http://jsfiddle.net/9gyw2byq/)

Thinking that maybe somehow the `min-height` property was getting clobbered by the animate method (or something), I tried resetting it manually after the animate

```
myTextArea.on('click', function() {
  myTextArea.animate({'height': '150px'}, 'slow');
  myTextArea.css('min-height': '10px');
);
```

But alas, no luck. Anyone know where I've gone wrong..?

Comment: store the original height and use that to reset with, or simply use `removeAttr('style')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can resize back to the original minimum height if and only if the user has already resized it using the drag handler.

There is no event to handle the resize of the textarea. There is no way to simulate it with `.trigger()`. The user has to do it and that's that.

It appears this is a known problem with textareas. You might be able to detect whether or not a user has done it by checking the textarea's `style.width` and `style.height` properties, but you can't force it to behave the way you want beforehand using traditional events.

If you really need this functionality, try the [Resizeble](http://jqueryui.com/resizable/#textarea) plugin. It overwrites the default textarea resize function with its own more robust handler. You can also create your own resize handler using a similar idea.

Answer (score 0):

try this:in css we use `,` not `:` .

```js
   $('textarea').animate({'height':'150px'}, 'slow');
        var  minheight = parseInt($('textarea').css('min-height'));
        console.log(minheight);
   $('textarea').on('click', function() {
              $(this).animate({'height': '100px'}, 'slow');
               $(this).css('min-height',minheight+'px');
   });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea placeholder="Click me!"  style="min-height:20px;"></textarea>
```

Comment: Doesn't fix the problem. Try your own snippet.

Comment: @Makaze what is it not re-sizing.will you explain what you want.

Comment: If a user resizes the textarea to 150px from the default manually, they can resize it back down to the minimum height. If you edit the height programmatically, the textarea's internal minheight gets changed and you can no longer resize it to below 150px. The asker wants it to be resizeable below 150px after animating the transition AFAIK.